# query ebay odata with linq

Tags: vb.net, linq, odata

I am pulling information from eBay using their odata feed. I am trying to use linq to pull the specific information we are after. Using linq I can get down to the specific element holding the information we want. What I can't do is figure out how to query the element data to get the specific child elements I want. I could just parse it but really want to learn linq. I am using vb.net as the language. To get the element I am after I use the following:

```
Sub Main
dim ns = "http://ebayodata.cloudapp.net/"
dim url as string = "http://ebayodata.cloudapp.net/Items?search=1756-L65"
    Using reader As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(url)
    While reader.Read()
        If reader.NodeType = XmlNodeType.Element AndAlso reader.Name =    "entry" Then
            GetChildContentElements(reader)
        End If

    End While
End Using
 End Sub


  Private Sub GetChildContentElements(reader As XmlReader)
' move to first child
While reader.Read()
    If reader.NodeType = XmlNodeType.Element AndAlso reader.Name = "m:properties" Then
        Exit While
    End If
End While
Dim bookXml As XElement = DirectCast(XNode.ReadFrom(reader), XElement)
Console.WriteLine(bookXml)

   End Sub
```

One of the elements this returns looks like:

```
<m:properties xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices">
  <d:Id>160917851201</d:Id>
  <d:UserId>baltisales</d:UserId>
  <d:Title>Allen Bradley 1756-L65 /B ControlLogix Processor 32MB Memory *60 DAYS WARRANTY!*</d:Title>
  <d:Subtitle m:null="true"></d:Subtitle>
  <d:SellingState>Active</d:SellingState>
  <d:TimeLeft>P24DT2H25M33S</d:TimeLeft>
  <d:Currency>USD</d:Currency>
  <d:CurrentPrice m:type="Edm.Double">6446.14</d:CurrentPrice>
  <d:MinimumToBid m:type="Edm.Double">6446.14</d:MinimumToBid>
  <d:BidCount m:type="Edm.Int32">0</d:BidCount>
  <d:Description m:null="true"></d:Description>
  <d:QuantitySold m:type="Edm.Int32">0</d:QuantitySold>
  <d:AutoPay m:type="Edm.Boolean">false</d:AutoPay>
  <d:CharityId m:null="true"></d:CharityId>
  <d:Country>US</d:Country>
  <d:Compatibility m:null="true"></d:Compatibility>
  <d:GalleryUrl>http://thumbs2.ebaystatic.com/m/m3Y01PfuyFhctnJiEet95Gw/140.jpg</d:GalleryUrl>
  <d:GlobalId>EBAY-US</d:GlobalId>
  <d:PostalCode>21209</d:PostalCode>
  <d:ReturnsAccepted m:type="Edm.Boolean">true</d:ReturnsAccepted>
  <d:PrimaryCategoryId>97184</d:PrimaryCategoryId>
  <d:SecondaryCategoryId m:null="true"></d:SecondaryCategoryId>
  <d:ViewItemUrl>http://www.ebay.com/itm/Allen-Bradley-1756-L65-B-ControlLogix-Processor-32MB-Memory-60-DAYS-WARRANTY-/160917851201?pt=BI_Control_Systems_PLCs</d:ViewItemUrl>
  <d:PaymentMethods>PayPal ,VisaMC ,AmEx</d:PaymentMethods>
  <d:Condition m:type="eBay.Model.Entities.Condition">
    <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">3000</d:Id>
    <d:Name>Used</d:Name>
  </d:Condition>
  <d:ListingInfo m:type="eBay.Model.Entities.ListingInfo">
    <d:BestOfferEnabled m:type="Edm.Boolean">true</d:BestOfferEnabled>
    <d:BuyItNowAvailable m:type="Edm.Boolean">false</d:BuyItNowAvailable>
    <d:BuyItNowPrice m:type="Edm.Double" m:null="true"></d:BuyItNowPrice>
    <d:ConvertedBuyItNowPrice m:type="Edm.Double" m:null="true">  </d:ConvertedBuyItNowPrice>
    <d:Gift m:type="Edm.Boolean">false</d:Gift>
    <d:ListingType>StoreInventory</d:ListingType>
    <d:StartTime m:type="Edm.DateTime">2012-11-06T23:08:18Z</d:StartTime>
    <d:EndTime m:type="Edm.DateTime">2013-04-05T23:13:18Z</d:EndTime>
  </d:ListingInfo>
  <d:Distance m:type="eBay.Model.Entities.Distance" m:null="true"></d:Distance>
  <d:ShippingInformation m:type="eBay.Model.Entities.ShippingInformation">
    <d:Delimiter m:null="true"></d:Delimiter>
    <d:ExpeditedShipping m:type="Edm.Boolean">true</d:ExpeditedShipping>
    <d:HandlingTime m:type="Edm.Int32">1</d:HandlingTime>
    <d:OneDayShippingAvailable m:type="Edm.Boolean">true</d:OneDayShippingAvailable>
    <d:ShippingServiceCost m:type="Edm.Double">0</d:ShippingServiceCost>
    <d:ShippingType>FlatDomesticCalculatedInternational</d:ShippingType>
  </d:ShippingInformation>
</m:properties>
```

I am struggling with querying the above to get the specific child elements we need to work with. The ":" in the tags seems to be confusing using namespaces. What I would like to do is to be able to query the element to get values for d:Id, d:UserId, d:Currentprice, etc. Any suggestions would be welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample code for doing custom url's with generated WCF DS client,

```
const string baseAddress = "http://ebayodata.cloudapp.net/";
EBayData ebay = new EBayData(new Uri(baseAddress));

var items = ebay.Execute<Item>(new Uri(baseAddress + "Items?search=1756-L65"));
foreach (var item in items)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Title);
}
```

Comment: Thank you RaghuRam. That is great. This greatly simplifies what I was trying to do and helps me understand the syntax of Linq a little better.

Answer (score 1):

Try using WCF data services client. It can generate proxy classes for you that would simplify things. Refer to the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd673930.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I just tried experimenting with using WCF with this service but have not been successful. Probably because of my lack of knowledge of this subject. In my experiments the eBay service does not seem to follow the typical oData format in that the search term is  required in the URI, e.g., http://ebayodata.cloudapp.net/Items?search=1756-L65. WCF does not seem to accept this format. I can establish the service reference in my project and see the methods, but have not been successful in getting results.